# Disable button once pressed and re enable button after a set period of time

Tags: button, actionscript-2

Im working with `Flash Actionscript 2.0`

How would I disable a button once pressed, and after a defined period of time, allow this button to be re-enabled or reset?

Answer (score 2):

That's simple. Try this:

Your button will be enabled in 10 seconds after it's clicked.

timeline:

```
myBtn.onRelease = function() {
    this.enabled = false;
    enabledB = setInterval(enabledBtn,10000); //control activate time
}

function enabledBtn(){
    myBtn.enabled = true; 
    clearInterval(enabledB);
}
```